# Add filters in ng-init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

```
<input ng-model="search.name" placeholder="Name" />

<tbody>
<div ng-init="FilteredGeojson = ho|filter:search">
<tr ng-repeat="hf in FilteredGeojson">
    <td>{{ hf.name }}</td>   
</tr>
</div>
</tbody>
</table>
<div leaflet-directive id="map" data="FilteredGeojson"></div>
```

It is important to do filtering in ng-init if it is possible, but i cannot solve it, i cannot make ng-repeat and create scope which i pass after to my directive cause it start infinite digest loop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### The answer to your question

Your snippet doesn't work because of `ho` and `filter:search` are different statements. In

```
ng-init="FilteredGeojson = ho | filter:search"
```

... the assignment `FilteredGeojson = ho` is done before the filter `| filter:search` is applied, which does not work.

You need to encapsulate filtering the value like this:

```
ng-init="FilteredGeojson = (ho | filter:search)"
```

### Also

> It is important to do filtering in ng-init

Important for what? `ngInit` directive will be called only once there, so when you'll update your filter, items in `ngRepeat` wouldn't be updated. But you need this, right?

To achieve this you should add filter in `ngRepeat` directive, like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="hf in FilteredGeojson | filter:search">
    <td>{{ hf.name }}</td>   
</tr>
```

### Example

Both solutions are available in [this plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/nFFHmUA7RdxMIPV9VUDC?p=preview).

Comment: There is something else i want to use ng-init for other directive and when i did sth like this   <input ng-model="search" placeholder="Name" />
  <table ng-init="FilteredGeojson = (Geojson | filter:search)">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in FilteredGeojson | filter:search">
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div>{{FilteredGeojson}}</div>
</body>     FilteredGeojson in <div> is not changing, how to influence it as well?

Comment: Nononono, don't write code in the comments, firstly. Update your answer. I had provided fully working plnkr and its ok. Did I answered your question? If you need to do more, add explanation to the question, but it is better to create new. This one is solved.

Comment: it is not solved in my question i pass ng-init after filtering by scope into another directive, you haven't done so in your plnkr, I asked how to make filtering just in ng-init, your example is not working if i delete filter search from ng-repeat.

Comment: And my second statement says clearly that i cannot use ng-repeat

Comment: @IOR88, exactly. Why you cannot use ngRepeat? That means you have complex architecture problem. You didn't explained that at all. Statements in ngInit are fired 1 time, so it wouldn't work with runtime filter: ngInit wouldn't fire on ngInit. Another way is to use `$watch` on `$scope.filter`, but it is monstrous. You have to use ngRepeat, where you need to use ngRepeat that's all.

Comment: i made new question with fiddler  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28464558/ng-repeat-causing-infinitive-digest-loop-when-passing-scope-to-leaflet-directive

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ng-init` here but an improvised use of `ng-repeat`.
Here is the updated [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/h1OD0bxH6x6Bvr7x3gbN/).

Here is the index.html in the plnkr.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-semver="1.3.13" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.3.x"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  FilteredGeojson.length :- {{FilteredGeojson.length}}
  <br>
  <input ng-model="search" placeholder="Name" /> {{ search }}
  <table >
    <tr ng-repeat="item in (FilteredGeojson = (Geojson | filter:search))">
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>


</html>
```

`FilteredGeojson` will be updated when you changed `search` variable on the scope using input box. I updated the plnkr to show this.

Also, if the `Geojson` array is a long array, you can use `limitTo` filter like this.

`<tr ng-repeat="item in (FilteredGeojson = (Geojson | filter:search)) | limitTo: 5">`

Let me know if it helped or not.

Answer (score -1):

I use the example of Sharikov Vladislav. thanks by the way.

for me it's work only without "filter" :

```
<div class="centerdivConteneur" ng-init="$root.breadcrumb.label = '<li><a href=\'#\'>Index</a></li><li>' +('Plan du site'|translate)+'</li>'">
```

(this page have no controller )